# IBDesignable not displaying programmatic UI elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, ibdesignable

I created a custom ViewController class, `ViewControllerRootHomeCenter` which is inheriting from UIViewController, and checked the box to create a accompanying XIB file.  I set the `File's Owner` Custom Class attribute to `ViewControllerRootHomeCenter`.  I then created a couple of UI elements in the viewDidLoad method to see if they are loading on the device, and the simulator, which they are in fact displaying on the screen.  Then in the `ViewControllerRootHomeCenter.h` file I set `IB_DESIGNABLE` above the `@interface ViewControllerRootHomeCenter` statement.  However the XIB is displaying a white screen with no UI elements in it.

[image: empty XIB]

Answer (score 3):

Try this -> Paste the drawing UI elements code in `(void)prepareForInterfaceBuilder{ }` method (self calling method for Live rendering purpose)

Answer (score 2):

You also need to set the properties to be `IBInspectable` then they will appear in the XIB File as you want.

[image: Code]

[image: XIB]

Take a look at this [link](http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/) to have more examples and see if something can help you up to find a solution to your case.

Comment: If I am creating the UI elements in the viewDidLoad method can I not set a IBInspectable attribute on it?  Or do all my UI elements need to be properties?

Comment: It must to be a property otherwise you won't see its reference in the XIB file...

Comment: created the properties, and set the reference to `strong` still not seeing anything :l

Comment: The thing is, you should create a subclass of UIElements to have a IBInspectable property, then you can set its color, border, size, etc... Not a UIViewController subclass... I think this is where you are having problems.

Comment: I am creating an instance of a `UINavigationBar` programmatically in the `viewDidLoad` method, I made it `strong` property, and set it to be `IBDesignable` but I am still not seeing it in IB.

Comment: forget that.. you need to have a subclass of UINavigationBar and then inside this class you can have an inspectable property